# Is there any way to handle this binding error?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I'm using a custom control CachedImage (github here- https://github.com/floydpink/CachedImage)

This control automatically caches images which I need because it dramatically speeds up my app. However, the control does not appear to handle when the image source is a dead link, which will happens sometimes in the app (ie. if a user removes their image for whatever reason) and is inavoidable.

When the control is set to have a source that is a dead link, the whole app crashes and I get a System.NotSupportedException "No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found".

First of all, **is there any way to try/catch these types of binding errors?** Regardless of how the custom control handles it, if I could handle this exception on my own, I could easily either ignore the image or give it a better source, or even ignore it. There's no reason for my whole app to crash. If I surround the statement that triggers the binding `Content.ItemsSource = query.ToList()` the app crashes while in the try loop, without even going to the catch block...

If not, **can I incorporate any error logic into the binding?** Another thing I feel like shouldn't be a problem would be setting a default value (some question mark type image to serve as default), however if I set FallBackValue or TargetNullValue to this image, the control still crashes when its source fails. I've read up a lot on binding, but it still seems like witchcraft to me, is there a way to selectively bind to the default image if the basic binding fails?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a IValueConverter with the binding and in the convert method handle for the null image source appropriately. For more info : [Converters](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html),   [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        //Handle 

    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Got this to work nicely by converting null to the default image I wanted, thank you